# turtle not is working i am trying to run i think it could be the IDE

Tags: python, import, ide, turtle-graphics

I am trying to fix a problem I have with python/turtle I thought I had done something wrong like miss spelling something in the IDE but then I ran the exact same code directly to python 3.8 (32-bit) and it worked fine the code I ran was:

```
import turtle 
Jeff = turtle.Turtle() 
turtle.done()
```

and the errors say

```
Module 'turtle' has no 'Turtle' member; maybe 'turtle'?
Module 'turtle' has no 'done' member
```

Comment: What's the name of your source file?

Comment: sorry I am new by source file you mean the folder ?

Comment: Can you tell the name of the python file you are executing. Name of the python files should not be same as the package/module names. If you save this code in file called turtle.py and execute it , it will not conisder the imported turtle package.  Rename it to some other name like turtle1.py or something else.